# Agregar clase activa una columna de tabla (como netflix)

Tags: vue.js

Necesito ayuda para seleccionar una cabecera de una tabla y que se seleccione su columna, con VueJS.
Soy novato en VueJS. Voy aprendiendo.

La idea seria como en Netflix en la seccion de planes al registrarse.

[Gif ejemplo](https://media.giphy.com/media/ggijcA7uQNH8CSfeaq/giphy.gif)

Para realizarlo, utilice un table:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="text-center">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"><button type="button" class="btn plan_columnA selected" @click="planSelect('plan_columnA')">Column A</button></th>
            <th scope="col"><button type="button" class="btn plan_columnB" @click="planSelect('plan_columnB')">Column B</button></th>
            <th scope="col"><button type="button" class="btn plan_columnC" @click="planSelect('plan_columnC')">Column C</button></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="text-center">
        <tr>
            <td class="plan_columnA selected">Mark</td>
            <td class="plan_columnB">Otto</td>
            <td class="plan_columnC">@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="plan_columnA selected">Jacob</td>
            <td class="plan_columnB">Thornton</td>
            <td class="plan_columnC">@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="plan_columnA selected">Larry</td>
            <td class="plan_columnB">the Bird</td>
            <td class="plan_columnC">@twitter</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Los estilos son:

```
.btn {
    background-color: darkgrey;
    color: white;
}
button.selected {
    background-color: red;
}
td.selected {
    color: red;
}
```

Intente hacerlo en Vue. El codigo es el siguiente:

```
    export default {
    data () {
        return {
            planSelected: '',
        }
    },

    methods: {
        planSelect (plan) {
            this.planSelected = plan;

            $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $('.' + this.planSelected).addClass('selected');
        },
    },
}
```

Que por cierto no es correcto, porque combine JQuery con Vue.
Tendria que utilizar propiedades computadas para retornar las clases?

Quisiera añadir la clase "selected" a todos los que le corresponda a la columna. Es decir, si selecciono la cabecera columna A, que se agreguen a todos los elementos que tengan la clase plan_columnA.

Probe lo siguiente, y agregando :class="classes" a los elementos que quiero resaltar.

```
    computed: {
        classes() {
            return this.planSelected ? 'selected' : ''
        }
    }
```

Pero esto obviamente selecciona todas las cabeceras y columna.

Comment: ay ya lo tenes. Es lo que hiciste abajo, pero como computada tenes que tener tantas como columnas tengas, y tantas variables como columnas tengas. Debe haber algo mejor.

Comment: también podrías hacerlo con CSS puro mediante una propiedad llamada Hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con:

```
<th scope="col"><button type="button" class="btn plan_columnA selected" @click="planSelect('plan_columnA')" :class="{'selected': planSelected === '' || planSelected === 'plan_columnA'}">Column A</button></th>
<th scope="col"><button type="button" class="btn plan_columnB selected" @click="planSelect('plan_columnB')" :class="{'selected': planSelected === 'plan_columnB'}">Column B</button></th>
<th scope="col"><button type="button" class="btn plan_columnC selected" @click="planSelect('plan_columnC')" :class="{'selected': planSelected === 'plan_columnC'}">Column C</button></th>
```

Y después puedes eliminar:

```
$('.selected').removeClass('selected');
$('.' + this.planSelected).addClass('selected');
```